# How we can get visible Cell IndexPath when a UICollectionView Loads its data initially

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

Is there any way that we can get indexPathsForVisibleItems when a UICollectionView loads its data initially . Basically I want all cell indexPaths which are currently visible on the screen. I am getting that in scrollViewDidScroll using below code.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self LoadVisibleItems];

  }

-(void)LoadVisibleItems
{
   NSArray* visibleCellIndex = self.myCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems;

  NSArray *sortedIndexPaths = [visibleCellIndex   sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSIndexPath *path1 = (NSIndexPath *)obj1;
    NSIndexPath *path2 = (NSIndexPath *)obj2;
    return [path1 compare:path2];
}];



NSIndexPath* newFirstVisibleCell = [sortedIndexPaths firstObject];
NSIndexPath* newLastVisibleCell = [sortedIndexPaths lastObject];


}
```

Comment: when viewDidLoad is called, the data and cells are not yet initialized, You want viewDidAppear instead

Answer (score 6):

Correct me if I misunderstand your question

If you load collectionView from storyboard

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray* visibleCellIndex = self.myCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems;
}
```

If you init collectionView by code after some view `addSubview` collectionView do

```
NSArray* visibleCellIndex = self.myCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems;
```

Comment: I have added the collection view programatically , I have already tried this code after I reload the collection view but its returning a blank array where as using same code I am getting index path in scrollViewDidScroll.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];
NSArray *ary = collectionView.visibleCells;
for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in ary) {
    NSIndexPath *path = [collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"indexPath of cell: %d - %d", (int)path.section, (int)path.row);
}
```

or use

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```